# Show that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that the polynomial $x^2 − 1\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[x]$ has at least $b$ roots.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> For every positive integer $b$, show that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that the
>   polynomial $x^2 − 1\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[x]$ has at least $b$ roots.

My thought is to use Euler's Theorem to find $\phi(n)$, then do $(x^{(2\phi(n)/2)})^b-1=0\;\pmod{n}$, then factorize the equation. Am I on the right way?

Comment: Beware that factorizing a polynomial modulo $n$ won't give you all the roots : for example $x(x-1)(x-2)$ has actually $6$ roots modulo $6$, and not $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $m$ and $n$ are coprime, there are $k$ solutions modulo $m$ and $l$ solutions modulo $n$, then how many solutions are there modulo $mn$?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Take $n$ to have at least $b$ odd prime factors and use the Chinese remainder theorem.